# Is there a syntax difference between template match and if test?

Tags: xslt

I'm currently trying to improve code and i came across this:

```
<xsl:template match="activator">
    <xsl:if test="not(ancestor::repeater)">
        Test1
    </xsl:if> 
</xsl:template>
```

since the if seemed not necessary i replaced it:

```
<xsl:template match="activator[not(ancestor::repeater)]">
    Test2
</xsl:template>
```

I tested it with

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<repeater>
    <activator>
        <text>
            <string>T_Auswahl</string>
        </text>
    </activator>
</repeater>
```

but it doesn't match now and i can't figure out what i did wrong.

Comment: "*but it doesn't match now*" An example would be most useful: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Re your added test: It doesn't match now because you don't have an `activator` node whose ancestor is not `repeater`.

Answer (score 1):

This does not answer your question as asked, but it could be important:

A template with a predicate, e.g.:

```
<xsl:template match="sigma[not(ancestor::alpha)]">
```

does not match nodes that do *not* satisfy the predicate, e.g. `/root/beta/lambda/omega`. If you don't have another template matching such nodes, the built-in template rules will be applied to them - resulting in possible unwanted copying of the text nodes to the output tree.